Symmetric matrix diagonalisation with symplectic transform
I have two $4\times 4$ matrixes
$$
\varepsilon=\text{diag}(E_1, E_2, E_1, E_2), \quad E_1, E_2 \geq 0,
$$
and $\beta$ general form positive definite symmetric matrix. Is there any way to diagonalize or, at least, make block-diagonal matrix $\beta$ using only symplectic transforms and preserve diagonal form of $\varepsilon$?
I know that in case of $2\times 2$ matrixes
$$
\varepsilon=\text{diag}(E, E), \quad E\geq 0
$$
the answer is yes. Indeed, let's transform $\beta$ into a diagonal shape using an orthogonal transformation. In this case, the shape of $\varepsilon$ will not change. If the determinant of this orthogonal transformation is $1$, then this is a rotation, and this is a symplectic transformation. If the determinant of this orthogonal transformation is $-1$, then we perform another reflection, which also does not change the shape of the $\varepsilon$ and $\beta$.
